# Multiple Backup Jobs Simultaneously: Theory vs Practice

Tags: linux, multithreading, backup

While designing a fairly simple backup system for Linux in python, I'm finding myself asking the question, **could there be any time advantage to backing up up several datasets/archives simultaneously?**

My intuition tells me that writing to several archives simultaneously would not buy me much time as I/O would already be the greatest bottleneck.

On the other hand, if using something like bz2, would there be an advantage with multi-threading since higher demand of CPU will decrease I/O demand?  Or is it a wash since all threads would be doing essentially the same thing and therefore sharing the same bottlenecks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your system. If you have multiple disks, it could be very worthwhile to parallelize your backup job. If you have multiple processors, compressing multiple jobs in parallel may be worth your while.

If the processor is slow enough (and the disks are fast enough) that zipping makes your CPU a bottleneck, you'll make some gains on multicore or hyperthreaded processors. The reduced I/O demand from zipped data being written is almost certainly a win if your CPU can keep up with the read speed of your drive(s).

Anyway, this is all very system dependent. Try it and see. Run two jobs at once and then run the same two in serial and see which took longer. The cheap (coding-wise) way is to just run your backup script twice with different input and output parameters. Once you've established a winner, you can go farther down the path.